# Why won't these form elements with width 50% display on one line?

Tags: html, css, forms, width

I have two form elements (a text input and a submit button), that I want to display on one line, both with a width of 50%. This doesn't work with the following HTML/CSS:

HTML

```
  <form name="newsletter" target="#" method="post" class="group">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email here..." />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="subscribe" />
  </form>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

input[type="text"] {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 0.75rem; /* 16x0.75=12px */
    padding: 0.625em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0.3125em 0.3125em;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 0.75rem; /* 16x0.75=12px */
    padding: 0.625em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0.3125em 0.3125em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Setting them to `display:block` or `inline-block` doesn't help either. But when I set them both to `width:50%`, and `float:left` and `float:right` they stay on one line without a problem.

Why is that?

Comment: They display on one line for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/3NzTL/ which browser are you using?

Comment: @darkajax: Firefox (latest version)

Comment: @darkajax: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3NzTL/1/, I'd accidentally copied the wrong css, this version has the right css (corrected it in the question too).

Comment: If you want to use `inline-block`, you'll have to remove the whitespace in your html or zero it out via CSS, and if you want to use the `box-sizing` property you'll need to include the correct vendor prefixes.

Comment: @BG_Insight: I included the vendor-prefixes, just left them out here for brevity (although it might be confusing). Do I zero out the whitespace on the form element?

Comment: @Samuel there are several solutions to that approach in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this style:

```
input{float:left}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have whitespace (newlines, tabs, etc.) between your elements.  Remove it (or comment it out), and they fit as you would expect:

http://tinker.io/9a125

```
  <form name="newsletter" target="#" method="post" class="group">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email here..." /><!--
    --><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="subscribe" />
  </form>
```

Inline* elements honor whitespace between them.  The reason floating works is because the elements are no longer inline.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have also set a border of 1px which will add to the 50%.

Comment: That's cool. There is no support in ie 6/7 though. Although that shouldn't matter in 2013, clients still ask...